# Overriding NS*** methods in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

To provide a fallback language for `NSLocalizedString`, I'm using this `#undef` and `#define` in Objective-C:

```
#undef NSLocalizedString
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) @"NSLocalizedString has been replaced";
```

This works perfectly well if called from Objective-C, but if called from Swift, the new definition of `NSLocalizedString` is ignored. (bridging header is configured correctly and works)

Is this possible in Swift, and if so, how?

---

Note: the real example is [here on Github](https://github.com/drosenstark/categories), also see [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26347528/8047)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this for `NSObject` subclasses like this

```
extension NSObject {
    func NSLocalizedString(key: String, comment: String) -> String {
        return "yes we have localized an NSObject"
    }
}
```

What about `AnyObject`? In this case, you would have to be aware of and conform to the `FallbackLanguage` protocol in your `AnyObject` subclass

```
protocol FallbackLanguage: class {}

// add default implementations
extension FallbackLanguage {
    func NSLocalizedString(key: String, comment: String) -> String {
        return "yes we have localized AnyObject via FallbackLanguage protocol"
    }
}
```

---

**Notes**

- These two solutions can both be in your project without any issues.
- If you're calling `NSLocalizedString` outside of a class instance, you're out of luck.

Comment: Big thanks to this answer for how to extend AnyObject: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31988258/8047

Comment: Or you could just extend UIViewController, UIView and possibly some other classes where NSLocalizedString is called in virtually all cases.

Comment: so narrow this to several unrelated superclasses which happen to all share nsobject as their super?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right. I focused on the AnyObject extension discussion and forgot about that virtually everything that inherits from the API also inherits from NSObject.

Comment: This used to work, but suddenly I get:


"Use of instance member 'NSLocalizedString' on type 'NSObject'; did you mean to use a value of type 'NSObject' instead?"

and 
"Extra argument 'comment' in call"

Comment: @ColinSwelin just tried this in a playground with no issues. Please post a playground (as a gist on Github or whatever) and perhaps we can help?

Comment: @ColinSwelin I'm seeing what Colin is too. "Extra Argument in call".

Comment: @jasonjwwilliams what version of Swift are you using? On Swift 2.x this works well... not sure about Swift 3

Comment: still good in Swift 3, https://gist.github.com/drosenstark/a1dd2fd53a3041c92922e53c8a931012

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do a global function... the other options will cause all sort of problems,  such as retrain cycles, or classes classes witch do not inherit from NSObject(that is only subset of the problems) - this will not work at all. yes global function usually are big no! but that is the only way to "override" global function. , 
Here is a code I use in production, we had few thousands of string, at some point we had to make our app dynamically localized - and this is what we did.

```
// Global functions for lagacy code
func NSLocalizedString(_ key: String, comment: String) -> String {
    return key.localized()
}

func NSLocalizedStringInTable(key: String, tableName: String ) -> String {
    return key.localized(using: tableName)
}
```